# Why is my Wordpress admin not working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-admin, admin

My WordPress admin has stopped working. This is running with WooCommerce. On the Customize Appearance > WooCoomerce > Store Notice, I tried to set the Store Notice to Off. I got this error message:

```
changeset_post_save_failure()
```

I first tried to deactivate the plugins but they still remain activated. I am unable to edit any page or post.

As of a day before, I was still able to add a page. I remember this was after I had updated the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps to update the auto increment of the posts table in the link below. The admin of the site is now working. I am able to update the posts

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62974292/getting-wordpress-error-changeset-post-save-failure-on-customizer